# How to set primary SMTP address with Graph API?

Tags: c#, wpf, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I've some issues with the Graph API. I create a user (userPrincipalName = 001XX1234@domain.com), assign a licence, but i'm not able to add an alias or set the primary SMTP address.

Tried to use otherMails, but i can't get it to work ... (no error either).

```
var token = await GetToken();
var client = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) => { requestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
return Task.FromResult(0);
}));

var user = new User
{
  OtherMails = new List<String>()
  {
    "testalias@domain.com"
  }
};

await client.Users["001XX1234@domain.com"].Request().UpdateAsync(user);
```

Also tried

```
OtherMails = new[] { "testalias@domain.com" }
```

Any ideas?

**Update 15. January 2020:**

Still no success ...

```
        var token = await GetToken();
        var client = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
        {
            requestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);

        }));

        var blaaaa = await client
        .Users["001XX1234@domain.com"]
        .Request()
        .UpdateAsync(new User()
        {
            OtherMails = new[] { "testalias@domain.com" },
            GivenName = "Peter",
            DisplayName = "Hansen, Peter",
            Surname = "Hansi"
        });
```

It works for GivenName, DisplayName and Surname, but not for the mail.

Comment: Still no success ... tried also `'otherMails': ['testalias@domain.com']"` when i create the user. Nothing ;(

Somewhere i read something about a PATCH statement, but what does this mean: _You need to make a PATCH request to the users endpoint_?